# Quadratic variation of the Brownian motion and Itō's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $\mathcal P$ be a sequence of countable subsets $$\mathcal P^n:=\left\{\cdots<t_i^{(n)}<t_{i+1}^{(n-1)}<\cdots\right\}$$ of $[0,\infty)$ such that

  - $0\in\mathcal P^n\subseteq\mathcal P^{n+1}$
  - $\sup\mathcal P^n=\infty$
  - $\displaystyle|\mathcal P^n|:=\sup_{t\in\mathcal P^n}\min_{s\in\mathcal P^n:s\ne t}|s-t|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$
- $\mathcal P_T^n:=\mathcal P^n\cap [0,T)$
- $t':=t_{i+1}^{(n)}\wedge T$, if $t=t_i^{(n)}$

How can we show, that $$\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}f(B_t)(B_{t'}-B_t)^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\int_0^Tf(B_s)\;ds$$ in probability?

---

I've found a [proof (Theorem 7.12)](http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf), but I absolutely don't understand what they are doing. They state, that "[if $\tau$ is] the first exit time from a compact interval [...] it suffices to prove the statement for [the] Brownian motion stopped at $\tau$".

What do they mean by "first exit from a compact interval $K$? Maybe $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge 0:B_t\not\in K\right\}\;?$$

Why is that sufficient?

Comment: Have a look at these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1199785/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/822284/

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what they mean by "first exit from interval $K$"

Comment: @ConradoCosta Why is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\tau_L = \inf\{t \geq 0, |B_t|>L\}$. Note that $\tau_L \uparrow \infty$ and therefore $\Bbb{P}(\tau_L<n) \xrightarrow[L \to \infty]{} 0$ by the bounded convergence theorem.

That is sufficient because once you prove 
$$ \lim \sum_{j=1}^n f(B_{t^{(n)}_j})(t^{(n)}_{j+1} \wedge T - t^{(n)}_{j}\wedge T) \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{\text{prob}}\sum\int_0^{t\wedge T} f(B_s)\, ds$$

You will know that

$$  \Bbb{P}\bigg(\bigg\vert\lim\sum_{j=1}^n f(B_{t^{(n)}_j})(t^{(n)}_{j+1}  - t^{(n)}_{j}) -\sum\int_0^{t} f(B_s)\, ds \bigg\vert \geq \epsilon\bigg) \leq \\\Bbb{P}\bigg(\bigg\vert\lim\sum_{j=1}^n f(B_{t^{(n)}_j})(t^{(n)}_{j+1} \wedge \tau_L - t^{(n)}_{j}\wedge \tau_L) -\sum\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_L} f(B_s)\, ds \bigg\vert \geq \epsilon\bigg) + \Bbb{P}(t\geq \tau_L)$$

$\Bbb{P}(t \geq \tau_L) \xrightarrow[L\to \infty]{} 0$

Choose $L $ such that $\Bbb{P}(t \geq \tau_L) <\epsilon/2$ and then choose $n$ such that
$$\Bbb{P}\bigg(\bigg\vert\lim\sum_{j=1}^n f(B_{t^{(n)}_j})(t^{(n)}_{j+1} \wedge \tau_L - t^{(n)}_{j}\wedge \tau_L) -\sum\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_L} f(B_s)\, ds \bigg\vert \geq \epsilon\bigg) <\epsilon/2.$$

Comment: What you've written is clear to me. However, I don't see how this is related to the statement.

Comment: So, we' ve got $$\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}f(B_t)(B_{t'}-B_t)^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\int_0^Tf(B_s)\;ds\tag{1}$$ in probability. And by the *Itô isometry* $$\operatorname E\left[\int_0^T F'(B_s)^2\;ds\right]=\operatorname E\left[\left(\int_0^T F'(B_s)\;dB_s\right)^2\right]\;.\tag{2}$$ Clearly, $(1)$ implies the existence of a almost surely convergent subsequence. But can we conclude by $(2)$, that $$\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}f(B_t)(B_{t'}-B_t)^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\int_0^Tf(B_s)\;dB_s$$ almost surely (for a subsequence)?

Comment: I will come back in a while.

Comment: could you supply more background? Is this a theorem in Peres?

Comment: No, but in the proof of *Theorem 7.13* (you can find the link to the textbook below) they state, that by $(1)$ and "the definition of stochastic integral, we can choose a subsequence such that the sum in $(1)$ converges almost surely to $\int_0^T f(B_s)\;dB_s$". I assume that the "definition of stochastic integral "part is referring to the Itô isometry. http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf

Comment: I think he does not say what you are saying. Suggestion: read it once again note that there are two terms you are interested in, the first one follows from the definition of stochastic integral while the second term follows from Th 7.12.

Comment: I was blind, but now I see. One last question: If we choose $f\equiv 1$ in $(1)$, then we see that $$\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}(B_{t'}-B_t)^2\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}T\tag{3}$$ in probability. $(3)$ means, that for all $\mathcal P$, there is a subsequence $\mathcal P'$ of $\mathcal P$, such that the *quadratic variation* of $B$ with respect to $\mathcal P'$ is almost surely equal to $T$. However, I've read that the quadratic variation of $B$ is almost surely equal to $T$ for any $\mathcal P$. Can you clarify my confusion?

Comment: Let me try. Name $X_n(T): \sum_{P^n_T} (B(t_{j+1}-B(t_j))^2$ you showed that $X_n(T) \to T$ in probability, this means that there is a subsequence $X_{n_k}(T)$ converging to $T$  almost surely (Use Borel Cantelli lemma + Chebyshev). This is consistent with the other sentence, once the quadratic variation of a martingale is defined as the limit in probability of such quadratic increments.